# Need to redirect to success page after jTweetsAnywhere post

Tags: jquery

I have a page that makes use of the jTweetsAnywhere code (from [here](http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/))

I want to be able to make use of a redirect once the page comes back after successfully posting the Tweet. Has anyone done anything like that and care to share the code?

Here is my current code. Would I just add a function within here?

```
<div id="tweetbox"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#tweetbox').jTweetsAnywhere({
      showTweetBox: {
         counter: false,
         width: 500,
         height: 60,
         label: '',
         defaultContent: '#MyTest http://stackoverflow.com'
      }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a OnSubmitted function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#tweetbox').jTweetsAnywhere({
      showTweetBox: {
         counter: false,
         width: 500,
         height: 60,
         label: '',
         defaultContent: '#MyTest http://stackoverflow.com',
         onTweet: function(textTweet, htmlTweet){
            //tweet send succes
            window.location.href = "newurl.html"
         }
      }
   });
</script>
```